# What is the difference of the function?

Tags: calculus

Compute the difference quotient f(x+h)-f(x)/h for the function f(x)= -x^2-4x-1.  Simplify your answer as much as possible.

I keep getting the answer -2x-h-1 however, that is incorrect.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x+h)=-(x+h)^2-4(x+h)-1$.

So, $f(x+h)-f(x)=x^2-(x+h)^2+4x-4(x+h)=-2xh-h^2-4h$.

Thus after dividing by $h$ we have: $-2x-h-4$.

I think you made the mistake while simplifying $4(x+h)=4x+\mathbf{4}h$

Comment: Besides that, the missing parentheses in your difference quotient f(x+h)-f(x)/h cannot be a good sign.